# Trying to test a nested serilailzer, how to create required subfactories?

Tags: python, django, pytest, factory-boy

I am getting a failing test because (I think) I can't add a subfactory field.

I have a serializer that calls on another serializer. I am finding it difficult to replicate this in a test (specifically the factory). The issue is caused by my test: `_expected_restuarant_response`. It is expecting a response that includes an employee field (like the serializer does). The problem is that I can't add this subfactory field to `RestaurantFactory` because `RestaurantFactory` is located above `EmployeeFactory` in the factories.py file (`EmployeeFactory` has not yet been initialised at that point in the file). I also can't put `EmployeeFactory` higher than `RestaurantFactory` because it refers to `RestaurantFactory`.

Could somebody point me in the right direction? Thank you.

A simplified version of my files:

models.py:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Employee(models.Model):
    badge_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
```

serializers.py:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = [
            'badge_id']

class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee = EmployeeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = [
            'name',
            'employee']
```

factories.py:

```
class RestaurantFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Faker('company')
         < ----------------------------------- do I need to add an Employee subfactory here? If so how?

class EmployeeFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    badge_id = factory.Faker('id')
    restaurant = factory.SubFactory(RestaurantFactory)
```

test.py:

```
def _expected_restuarant_response(restaurant):
    return {
        restaurant.name,
        restaurant.employee_set.badge_id     <---- the test fails here because the RestaurantFactory does not include this field
         }

assert response_json == [_expected_restaurant_response(RestaurantFactory())]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the Factory creation you could probably do something like this:

```
class RestaurantFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Faker('company')
    employee = factory.SubFactory('path.to.EmployeeFactory', employee=None)
```

then on EmployeeFactory do this:

```
class EmployeeFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    badge_id = factory.Faker('id')
    restaurant = factory.RelatedFactory(RestaurantFactory, factory_related_name='employee')
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Do you know what would the 'path.to.EmployeeFactory' be if both factories are in the same file? I've tried just putting 'EmployeeFactory' but receive an error: ```E   ValueError: A factory= argument must receive either a class or the fully qualified path to a Factory subclass; got 'EmployeeFactory' instead.```

Comment: Should be the absolute path of the factory file (e.g: 'myproject.api.tests.factories.EmployeeFactory')